# How to use windows bootloader instead of grub using UEFI?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, bootloader, grub-efi

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual boot installed on my laptop. Currently, I am using grub as my bootloader. Is possible to use Windows bootloader instead of grub while using UEFI?

I have grub installed in this path: `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` in SYSTEM partition.

Here is the output of `bcdedit.exe /enum`:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=Z:
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {...}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {...}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {...}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

Comment: Suggest instead you put Windows Boot Manager as the first line in GRUB so it will autolaunch if you do nothing. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters for editing tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows bootloader will give you no choice between systems and will load only Windows. You can change loader through Bios setting priority of Windows loader higher than Grub

Comment: So your answer is that it is not possible, right?

Comment: @masec, yes, as I know. You can use grubcustomizer to fit Grub to your taste

Answer (score 0):

Yo hey, ik, this is an old post, but, you can use EasyBCD to add a boot entry on Windows Boot loader, not the best, but a fine solution, and then, you can put the win bl to the priority than the grub